# @Profile does not work without Spring Boot (-Dspring.profiles.active with maven)

Tags: java, spring, maven, spring-profiles, spring-properties

I'm having trouble to make `@Profile` work with maven and without Spring Boot.
In pom.xml I have defined maven profiles ("env" and "dev" which is also default).

Unfortunetly whenever I try to build project with:

```
mvn clean install -Dspring.profiles.active=env
```

The "default" profile is always applied (in Spring - maven applies "env" for maven purpose).
I have also tried to make it work with `System.getProperty("spring.profiles.active")` and `System.getenv("spring.profiles.active")` but those always returned null. I think it is also worth to mention that this is non-web application.

Beans (to read proper properties):

```
    @Bean
    @Profile({"default"})
    public static PropertySourcesPlaceholderConfigurer defaultProperties() {
        return getPropertySourcesPlaceholderConfigurer("db.yml");
    }

    @Bean
    @Profile({"env"})
    public static PropertySourcesPlaceholderConfigurer envProperties() {
        return getPropertySourcesPlaceholderConfigurer("db-env.yml");
    }

    @Bean
    @Profile({"test"})
    public static PropertySourcesPlaceholderConfigurer devProperties() {
        return getPropertySourcesPlaceholderConfigurer("db-test.yml");
    }

    private static PropertySourcesPlaceholderConfigurer getPropertySourcesPlaceholderConfigurer(String resource) {
        PropertySourcesPlaceholderConfigurer propertySourcesPlaceholderConfigurer = new PropertySourcesPlaceholderConfigurer();
        YamlPropertiesFactoryBean yaml = new YamlPropertiesFactoryBean();
        yaml.setResources(new ClassPathResource(resource));
        final Properties object = yaml.getObject();
        if (object != null) {
            propertySourcesPlaceholderConfigurer.setProperties(object);
        }
        return propertySourcesPlaceholderConfigurer;
    }
```

Pom.xml:

```
<profiles>
    <profile>
      <id>dev</id>
      <activation>
        <activeByDefault>true</activeByDefault>
        <property>
          <name>spring.profiles.active</name>
          <value>dev</value>
        </property>
      </activation>
    </profile>
    <profile>
      <id>env</id>
      <activation>
        <property>
          <name>spring.profiles.active</name>
          <value>env</value>
        </property>
      </activation>
    </profile>
  </profiles>
```

Comment: `mvn clean install -Dspring.profiles.active=env ` this pass java properties to maven NOT to your application.

Comment: Try with `--spring.profiles.active=env`

Comment: @lukaszrys May I know how you solved this one? I am facing same issue in my no-spring boot testing project, and trying to run like:

     mvn clean test -Dspring.profiles.active=p1
     mvn clean test -Pp1 (with maven profile)

but I see no profiles are taking effect when running.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The Spring profiles are for running your appplication, not building.  Pass the `-Dspring.profiles.active=env` when you execute your application.  In your example you are doing a `mvn install` which does not execute your application.

Comment: Your statement is mostly true, but there are cases when you want to specify the spring profile in the build. For example, if you are packaging an application into a war file for deployment to a container, e.g. Tomcat, you may want to specify the active profiles in the config file packaged inside the war.

Answer (score 1):

You need to specify the Maven profile (not the Spring profile) when running the command:

```
mvn clean install -Penv
```

See: http://maven.apache.org/guides/introduction/introduction-to-profiles.html

Comment: the maven profile activates due to `<activation>
        <property>
          <name>spring.profiles.active</name>
          <value>env</value>
        </property>
      </activation>`. The spring profile does not activate

Comment: Try `<profile>
   <id>env</id>
   <properties>
    <active.profiles.spring>env</active.profiles.spring>
   </properties>
  </profile>` You can specify a default activation, but beyond that you need to tell Maven which profiles are active.

Comment: This is the syntax I use when specifying a default: `<profile>
   <id>dev</id>
   <activation>
    <activeByDefault>true</activeByDefault>
   </activation>
   <properties>
    <active.profiles.spring>dev</active.profiles.spring>
   </properties>
  </profile>`, which is a little different than how you are using it, though I don't pretend to know all the different ways you can do things in Maven. But try my command above, specifying the Maven profile explicitly and see what that does for you.